# SQL grouping datas by 10min step

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I want to sort average duration times, names and id of processes launched during the last hour, sorted and grouped by steps of 15 minutes

Here are my tables :

**process**

- id
- Name
- Type

**processRun**

- id
- processid
- dateStart
- dateEnd

Here is my sql query :

```sql
WITH tps AS (
       SELECT sysdate-1/24,trunc(TO_DATE((trunc(sysdate,'MI')-MOD(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'MI'),15)/(24*60))-1/24) + (level) / 96, 'mi') AS DATEREF
       FROM dual
       CONNECT BY level <= 96 * (TO_DATE(SYSDATE) - TO_DATE(((trunc(sysdate,'MI')-MOD(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'MI'),15)/(24*60))-1/24)-1/24))
    ),
da AS (
        SELECT p.id as Id, p.Name as Nom,trunc(pRun.DateStart,'MI') as dateStart, AVG(pRun.DATEEND - pRun.DATESTART)*1440 as VAL
        FROM process p
        JOIN processrun pRun ON pRun.processid = p.id
        WHERE trunc(pRun.DateStart,'MI') BETWEEN trunc(SYSDATE-1/24,'MI') AND trunc(SYSDATE,'MI')
        AND p.Id = 92
   )
SELECT da.Id, da.Nom, da.VAL, da.dateStart, tps.dateref
FROM tps
LEFT JOIN da ON da.dateStart BETWEEN tps.dateref AND tps.dateref-15/1440
GROUP BY tps.dateref
ORDER BY da.dateStart, da.Nom ASC
```

This results in:

```
SELECT da.Id, da.Nom, da.VAL, da.dateStart, tps.dateref
ERROR at line 13:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

(with the `*` indicator positioned under `da.Id`)

I know I'm not doing this correctly, but I would like to group the results by a 10min-step, and I don't really know how to fix it with that `WITH` clause. Normally, I would just use the `GROUP BY tps.dateref`, but it is not working.

Thanks for the help!

---

Got it! my `GROUP BY` was false, because of my `AVG()`. I figured out how to fix it by juste select my `AVG()` during the last `SELECT` Here is my now query :

```
WITH tps AS (
   SELECT trunc(TO_DATE((trunc(sysdate,'MI')-MOD(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'MI'),15)/(24*60))-1/24) + (level) / 96, 'mi') AS DATEREF
   FROM dual
   CONNECT BY level <= 96 * (TO_DATE(SYSDATE) - TO_DATE(((trunc(sysdate,'MI')-MOD(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'MI'),15)/(24*60))-1/24)-1/24))
),
da AS (
    SELECT p.id as Id, p.Name as Nom,trunc(pRun.DateStart,'MI') as dateStart, pRun.DATEEND - pRun.DATESTART as VAL
    FROM process p
    JOIN processrun pRun ON pRun.processid = p.id
    WHERE trunc(pRun.DateStart,'MI') BETWEEN  trunc(SYSDATE-1/24,'MI') AND  trunc(SYSDATE,'MI')
    AND p.Id = 92
 )
SELECT da.Id,da.Nom, AVG(da.VAL)*1440,tps.dateref
FROM tps
LEFT JOIN da ON da.dateStart BETWEEN tps.dateref-15/1440 AND tps.dateref
GROUP BY da.Id, da.Nom, tps.dateref
ORDER BY tps.dateref, da.Nom ASC
```

Comment: I recall having done something similar in the past. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11215496/1291428

Comment: thanks, @Sebas, i will check it out. it seems to be what i wanted to achieve. I will try to adapt my code with this help and come back for feed back :)

Comment: If the referenced answer unlocked you, I'll be very happy if you can upvote it

Comment: hi @Sebas, your answer helped me a little, but i finally figured out that my `GROUP BY` was false. I rewrote it so, i'll edit my question. Thanks fo your help, i figured out a lot of things with it! :)