# TSQL - Sum on time column with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Need to create a query, which will get summary of time during which was bit set ON/OFF.

Example:

```
╔═══════════════════════════╗
║           TABLE           ║
╠════╦════════╦═════╦═══════╣
║ ID ║  TIME  ║ BIT ║ VALUE ║
╠════╬════════╬═════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║ 13:40  ║  1  ║   5   ║
║  2 ║ 13:45  ║  1  ║   3   ║
║  3 ║ 13:50  ║  1  ║   1   ║
║  4 ║ 13:55  ║  0  ║   2   ║
║  5 ║ 14:00  ║  0  ║   7   ║
║  6 ║ 14:05  ║  1  ║   3   ║
║  7 ║ 14:10  ║  1  ║   4   ║
║  8 ║ 14:15  ║  0  ║   2   ║
║  9 ║ 14:20  ║  1  ║   2   ║
╚════╩════════╩═════╩═══════╝
```

I would like to have total summary of `TIME` (and `VALUE` - simpler one) when the `BIT` was `SET ON`:

```
13:40 - 13:50 = 10 mins
14:05 - 14:10 = 5 mins
14:20         = no end time, 0 mins
-----------------------------------------
                15 mins
```

Have found:

- [How to sum up time field in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725732/how-to-sum-up-time-field-in-sql-server) = Sort of good question, but there is static time as start (0:00:00) which won't work in this case
- [Aggregate function over a given time interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215272/aggregate-function-over-a-given-time-interval) = there is aggregation but not conditioned and works on all data

I thought that this could be done as a recursive function (passing last processed datetime), which will pass the last date which was handled, and sum the datetime since the `BIT` is `ON`.

SQL query for summing the VALUE (easy one):

```
SELECT SUM(Value)
FROM Table
WHERE Bit = 1
```

**How should I get total value of minutes (time), during which was the `BIT` set `ON`?**

---

**EDIT**: Query which can be used for testing:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
    ID INT Identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [TIME] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [BIT] BIT NOT NULL,
    [VALUE] INT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @Table([TIME],[BIT],[VALUE]) VALUES('13:40',1,5);
INSERT INTO @Table([TIME],[BIT],[VALUE]) VALUES('13:45',1,3);
INSERT INTO @Table([TIME],[BIT],[VALUE]) VALUES('13:50',1,1);
INSERT INTO @Table([TIME],[BIT],[VALUE]) VALUES('13:55',0,2);
INSERT INTO @Table([TIME],[BIT],[VALUE]) VALUES('14:00',0,7);
INSERT INTO @Table([TIME],[BIT],[VALUE]) VALUES('14:05',1,3);
INSERT INTO @Table([TIME],[BIT],[VALUE]) VALUES('14:10',1,4);
INSERT INTO @Table([TIME],[BIT],[VALUE]) VALUES('14:15',0,2);
INSERT INTO @Table([TIME],[BIT],[VALUE]) VALUES('14:20',1,2);
SELECT * FROM @Table;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LEAD function to get time in the next row and to calculate time interval. Then just group result by [bit]

```
WITH t AS(
SELECT
    [time],
    DATEDIFF(minute, [time], LEAD([time], 1, null) OVER (ORDER BY [time])) AS interval,
    [bit],
    [value]
FROM table1)
SELECT [bit], CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, SUM(interval), '00:00') AS TIME), SUM([value]) FROM t
GROUP BY [bit]
```

Comment: This is really easily readable and quite understandable. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: update: use OVER (ORDER BY [time]) rather then (BY [id]). Because Id doesn't have to be sequential. It may be guid or natural key

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues:  summing up the time and identify the adjacent values.  You can handle the second with the difference of row numbers approach.  You can handle the former by converting to minutes:

```
select bit, min(time), max(time),
       sum(datediff(minute, 0, time)) as minutes,
       sum(value)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by bit order by id) as seqnum_b
      from t
     ) t
group by (seqnum - seqnum_b), bit;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! However I see there is a problem when the distance (Seqnum - seqnum_b) would be same for more cases, You would get wrong results for aggregation functions - `MIN` would take very first occur and `MAX` would take the very last one.

Comment: @Tatranskymedved . . . Did you try this?  This works to find adjacent rows.  Perhaps you left out the `bit` in the `group by`.

Comment: TBH haven't tried, but I've tested it now. This is smart piece of code! Thanks for the idea, I wouldn't ever imagine this can be done this way. Anyway this is not full answer to the topic, it addresses only the part of it. Appreciate Your time! =)

Answer (score 1):

This is a "gaps and islands" problem, with a pretty standard solution.  I came up with this, which is pretty much the same as Gordon's, but has an extra step to calculate the intervals.  This is the only reason I am posting what is essentially a duplicate answer, I'm not sure that taking the difference in minutes from zero actually works?

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (id int, [time] TIME, [bit] BIT, value INT);
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 1, '13:40', 1, 5;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 2, '13:45', 1, 3;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 3, '13:50', 1, 1;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 4, '13:55', 0, 2;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 5, '14:00', 0, 7;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 6, '14:05', 1, 3;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 7, '14:10', 1, 4;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 8, '14:15', 0, 2;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 9, '14:20', 1, 2;
WITH x AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [bit] ORDER BY id) AS a_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS b_id FROM @table),
y AS (
    SELECT [bit], MIN([time]) AS min_time, MAX([time]) AS max_time, SUM(value) AS value FROM x GROUP BY a_id - b_id, [bit])
SELECT [bit], SUM(value) AS total_value, SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, min_time, max_time)) AS total_minutes FROM y GROUP BY [bit];
```

Results:

```
bit total_value total_minutes
0   11          5
1   18          15
```

As a *bonus* here is a solution that only solves the actual question, i.e. how much elapsed time is there when the BIT is set to 1:

```
WITH x AS (SELECT id, id - DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS grp FROM @table WHERE [bit] = 1), y AS (SELECT MIN(id) AS range_start, MAX(id) AS range_end FROM x GROUP BY grp)
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t1.[time], t2.[time])) AS minutes_elapsed FROM y INNER JOIN @table t1 ON t1.id = y.range_start INNER JOIN @table t2 ON t2.id = y.range_end;
```

Comment: After the update I can clearly see how it works, I had problems understand the initial query =/ Thanks for the answer, this should work fine!